# How to set product and category ID programmatically

Tags: magento2

We can set the category details i.e meta title,meta description as folllow

```
$category->setMetaTitle('meta title');
$category->setMetaDescription('meta description');
$category->setMetaKeyword('meta keywords')
```

Is it possible to set the category ID? also can we set the ID of product pro grammatically?  for example

```
$this->product->setStatus(1);
$this->product->setPrice('50');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Id fields are **auto increment primary key field at database(Mysql)** and  using magento code you can not set id field as per your wish. That field is related with  other table of that entity (i.e category,prodoct) using **foreign key**.

set Category id  as per own is not good idea and you should avoid that

*If you really want then you have to work at mysql level means use mysql query. disable auto increment  and set id .After changes , enable auto increment again but it is totally your risk.*

Comment: Thank you Amit!